# How do I add a link to a created icon (iconify)?

Tags: html, css

I created two icons (code below), I need them to serve as links, to go to the main page, how do I do it?

`<div class="container-flex"> <div class="container">  <iconify-icon class="dollar" icon="fa:dollar" style="color: #83bf4f;" width="50" height="50"></iconify-icon> <iconify-icon class="hand" icon="fa-solid:hand-holding" style="color: white;" width="70" height="70"></iconify-icon>   </div>`

Comment: Use the `a` tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User Anchor tags for HYPERLINKS, like given below

```
    <div class="container">
        <a href="https://www.google.com/"><iconify-icon class="dollar" icon="fa:dollar" style="color: #83bf4f;" width="50" height="50"></iconify-icon></a>
        <a href="https://www.google.com/"><iconify-icon class="hand" icon="fa-solid:hand-holding" style="color: white;" width="70" height="70"></a>
        </iconify-icon>
    </div>
```